# use selected dropdown box value as variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to use the selected value in a drop-down box as a PHP variable in my functions.php file. I tried using jquery-ajax

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
> $("#pa_color").change(function(){ 
> var result= $(this).val();          
> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  result;
> if (result.length == 0) {
> document.getElementById("tit").innerHTML = "";
> return;
> } else {
> var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
>     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
>     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
>      document.getElementById("tit").innerHTML =  xmlhttp.responseText;
>         }
>     }
>     xmlhttp.open("GET", "selectcolor.php?q=" + color, true);
>     xmlhttp.send();
>       });     
>   });
> ```

and can get the variable to show on the site using getElementById("demo") but get a 404 message when trying to call and process the variable using my selectcolor.php file. I would prefer using php only but will use whatever is necessary. I can get all the colors associated with each item using PHP

> ```
> $color = $product->get_attribute('pa_color');
> ```

but I only want the selected color. As you can see I'm new at this and my knowledge is limited. Thank you

Comment: color doesn't seem to be initialized on your `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: why are you mixing plain javascript with jQuery? Also, since you are using jQuery, why are you using XMLHttpRequest and not $.ajax?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pa_color').val()
```

Will output the selected value of the drop down element.

Use this to get the selected options text.

```
$('#pa_color option:selected').text();
```

Now you can use this value to be passed to your php file using AJAX or something.

Comment: I've used this code but nothing seemed to initialize the variable or activate the colorselect.php file.`$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pa_color").change(function(){ 
  var selected = $(this).val();  
 $.ajax({
        url: "colorselect.php", 
        type: "POST", 
        data: {selected : selected},
        success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
 } 
  });
   });
 });`

Comment: my colorselect.php file looks like`<?php
echo $_POST['selected '];
//echo $color` I don't know if the php file has to be placed in a certain file folder to make it work. mine is in my child-theme folder in wordpress.